# where __rvm_sed command defined

Tags: shell, rvm

I am reading the source code for RVM([RVM](https://rvm.io/)), which uses the command __rvm_sed, but I cannot find a definition of __rvm_sed in the source code. Can someone help with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After peeking at the [source code on Gitlab](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/tree/master), it looks like `__rvm_sed` is defined in the file [`scripts/functions/support`](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/master/scripts/functions/support):

```
line
 281  __rvm_setup_utils_functions
```

```
line
 175  __rvm_setup_utils_functions()
 176  {
 177    \typeset gnu_tools_path gnu_prefix gnu_util
 178    \typeset -a gnu_utils gnu_missing
 179    gnu_utils=( awk cp date find sed tail tar xargs )
 180    gnu_missing=()
 181  
 182    if is_a_function __rvm_setup_utils_functions_${_system_name}
 183    then __rvm_setup_utils_functions_${_system_name} "$@" || return $?
 184    else __rvm_setup_utils_functions_Other "$@" || return $?
 185    fi
 186  }
```

---

`_system_name` is (seemingly) defined in [`scripts/functions/detect/system`](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/blob/master/scripts/functions/detect/system), and can take one of the following values:

- "unknown"
- "Arch"
- "SuSE"
- "Devuan"
- "Sabayon"
- "Gentoo"
- "Arch"
- "Fedora"
- "Oracle"
- "CentOS"
- "Debian"
- "Synology"
- "Termux"
- "Solaris"
- "SmartOS"
- "OmniOS"
- "OpenIndiana"
- "FreeBSD"
- "OpenBSD"
- "DragonFly"
- "NetBSD"
- "OSX"
- "Cygwin"
- "Mingw"

---

So the script will try to invoke `__rvm_setup_utils_functions_${_system_name}` if that function exists, or fallback to `__rvm_setup_utils_functions_Other "$@"` ...

```
line
 252  __rvm_setup_utils_functions_Other()
 253  {
 254    __rvm_stat() { \command \stat "$@" || return $?; }
 255    __rvm_setup_utils_functions_common
 256  }
```

... which in turn invokes `__rvm_setup_utils_functions_common`:

```
line
 258  __rvm_setup_utils_functions_common()
 259  {
      (... snip ...)
 276    for gnu_util in "${gnu_utils[@]}"
 277    do eval "__rvm_$gnu_util() { \\$gnu_util \"\$@\" || return \$?; }"
 278    done
 279  }
```

So when `$gnu_util` is `sed`, function `__rvm_sed()` is `{ \sed "$@" || return $?; }`

Hope that helps.

Comment: awesome，thx!.  I think `__rvm_setup_utils_functions_common ` will resove my question.